# Using NDSolve to produce 10,000 points of a solution

Tags: differential-equations

I am beginning to read the *Differential Equations Laboratory Workbook* by Borelli and the preface begins with an image.

[image]

I understand how to use `NDSolveValue` (at a very beginning level), so I am wondering how I would use it to produce 10,000 points and duplicate this picture. I haven't yet learned how to use the `Methods` option. Perhaps one of the methods and a step size are available that will let me produce 10,000 points and a duplicate image.

Comment: Ah Lorenz… just use `NDSolve[]` like usual, and evaluate the component functions over 10000 equispaced points in your interval, using `Table[]` or `Range[]`.

Comment: On second thought: I haven't used it myself, but this seems like the sort of situation that calls for `ParametricNDSolve[]`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Are you saying that instead of using {t,0,10}, you can use Table or Range? Can I ask specifically how? What would that look like?

Comment: Well, you still need the `{t, 0, 10}` in `NDSolve[]` or its parametric variant. You can then do something like `Table[x1[t], {t, 0, 10, 10/(1*^4-1)}]` to get equispaced points.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a slightly different approach, using `ParametricNDSolve`:

```
sols = ParametricNDSolve[
  {x1'[t] == -10 x1[t] + 10 x2[t],
   x2'[t] == a1 x1[t] - x2[t] - x1[t] x3[t],
   x3'[t] == -(8/3) x3[t] + x1[t] x2[t],
   x1[0] == 1,
   x2[0] == 1,
   x3[0] == 1},
  {x1, x2, x3},
  {t, 0, 10},
  {a1}
 ];
```

This produces `ParametricFunction` objects, which take a value of the parameter `a1` first, but then can be plotted like any other function:

```
style = {12, FontFamily -> "Courier"};
lines = {
   Directive[Thickness[0.001], Black],
   Directive[Thickness[0.001] , Black, Dashing[0.005]]
  };
grid = Style[
   Grid[
    {{"x1'=-10x1+10x2", "x1(0):1.0", Item["t-zero 0", Alignment -> Right]},
     {"x2'=a1*x1-x2-x1*x3", "x2(0):1.0", Item["t-final 10", Alignment -> Right]},
     {"x3'=-(8/3)x3+x1*x2", "x3(0):1.0", Null}},
    Alignment -> Left, Spacings -> 4],
    Sequence @@ style];
legend = LineLegend[
   lines,
   {"{50}", "{55}"},
   LegendLabel -> "a1",
   LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1},
   LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 1},
   LabelStyle -> style
  ];

Labeled[
 Plot[
  Evaluate[(x1[#][t] & /@ {50, 55}) /. sols], {t, 0, 10},
  BaseStyle -> style,
  Axes -> False,
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "x1"},
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
  PlotStyle -> lines,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-30, 30}},
  ImageSize -> 1.5 {5, 3} 72],
Row[{legend, grid}, "\t"], Top]
```

[image: plot]

Pretty close!

*Aside:* the precision of the solution is important here. If we use a lower precision,

```
sols = ParametricNDSolve[
  {x1'[t] == -10 x1[t] + 10 x2[t],
   x2'[t] == a1 x1[t] - x2[t] - x1[t] x3[t],
   x3'[t] == -(8/3) x3[t] + x1[t] x2[t],
   x1[0] == 1,
   x2[0] == 1,
   x3[0] == 1},
  {x1, x2, x3},
  {t, 0, 10},
  {a1},
  WorkingPrecision -> 8
 ];
```

we get a graph that diverges from the first after a few time units!

[image: plot2]

Comment: In attempting to run your code, I got this error: ReplaceAll::reps: {%18} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

Comment: @David, sorry: I had a typo, which I've fixed now. In the `Plot`, I had `Out[18]`, which were my solutions, in place of `sols`, which is the name I gave them for this code.

Comment: No need to be sorry, as this is a wonderful contribution. There is a lot to learn here.

Comment: What I am wondering now is the difference in the interval from about 8 to 10. Your solution and Bob Hanlon's solution match, but differ from the image I provided, which makes me think that Borelli may have used a different method? Euler, Runga-Kutta? Something like that?

Comment: @David, it is probably in the numerics - this diffEQ is really sensitive to initial conditions, so it makes sense that it will also be sensitive to the numerical precision. This can be specified with the option `WorkingPrecision` in the `NDSolve` family. Both Bob Hanlon and I used the default precision (with is `MachinePrecision`) but I briefly checked that the solutions looks much different if you take something like `WorkingPrecision -> 8`. So probably, Borelli might have been using lower precision (the age of the book might tell you).

Comment: @David, you can specify specific methods to `NDSolve`, too via something like `Method -> "ExplicitEuler"` or `Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"`, so you can see if it make a difference on things like that too (probably). The default `NDSolve` method is mysterious, though usually very robust.

Comment: Not that mysterious, I think; the default method is based on LSODA, which is a blend of Adams and Gear multistep methods. Somewhat relatedly: if you want to force `NDSolve[]` to take fixed step sizes, you can coerce it to do so with the option setting [`Method -> "FixedStep"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveFixedStep.html).

Comment: But yes, Lorenz is notoriously sensitive ("butterfly effect") that a lowered precision in the initial values is indeed equivalent to a change in initial conditions.

Answer (score 8):

```
eqns = {
   x1'[t] == -10*x1[t] + 10*x2[t],
   x2'[t] == a1*x1[t] - x2[t] - x1[t]*x3[t],
   x3'[t] == -8*x3[t]/3 + x1[t]*x2[t],
   x1[0] == 1, x2[0] == 1, x3[0] == 1};

Plot[
 Evaluate[x1[t] /. Table[
    NDSolve[eqns, {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]}, {t, 0, 10},
      MaxStepFraction -> 1/10000][[1]],
    {a1, {50, 55}}]],
 {t, 0, 10},
 PlotStyle -> {ColorData[106, 1],
   Directive[ColorData[106, 2], AbsoluteDashing[{2, 3}]]},
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
 FrameLabel -> {"t", "x1"},
 Axes -> False,
 PlotLegends -> {"a1=50", "a1=55"},
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]