# Trouble with ParametricNDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

I have this:

```
eqns = {
   x1'[t] == -10 x1[t] + 10 x2[t],
   x2'[t] == a1 x1[t] - x2[t] - x1[t]*x3[t],
   x3'[t] == -(8/3) x3[t] + x1[t] x2[t]
   };
ics = {x1[0] == a, x2[0] == b, x3[0] == c};
```

Then this:

```
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqns, ics}, {x1, x2, x3}, {t, 0, 
   10}, {a1, a, b, c}]
```

But when I try to plot:

```
Plot[pfun[50, 1, 1, 1][t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

I get a blank image. What am I doing incorrectly?

**Due to Helpful Answers:** Thanks for the responses. Turns out the easiest answer for me is to replace the output {x1, x2, x3} with {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]}.

```
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqns, ics}, {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]}, {t, 0, 
   10}, {a1, a, b, c}];
Plot[Evaluate[pfun[50, 1, 1, 1]], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Which produces this image:

[image]

You can see why this works by entering:

```
pfun[50, 1, 1, 1]
```

Which produces this output:

{InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}}, <>][t], 
 InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}}, <>][t], 
 InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}}, <>][t]}

I can also grab the first solution for x1 with pfun[50, 1, 1, 1][[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaovH.png)]], which allows me to do things like the following:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{pfun[50, 1, 1, 1][[1]], pfun[50, 1.1, 1, 1][[1]]}], {t,
   0, 10}]
```

Which produces the following image:

[image]

See some further amazing help [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83034/using-ndsolve-to-produce-10-000-points-of-a-solution?noredirect=1#comment224311_83034). Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 8):

```
Plot[Evaluate[Through@pfun[50, 1, 1, 1]@t], {t, 0, 10}]
(* or Plot[#[t] & /@ pfun[50, 1, 1, 1], {t, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True] *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note: The parametric function `pfun[50, 1, 1, 1]` is a list of 3 `InterpolatingFunction`s:

```
pfun[50, 1, 1, 1]
```

> {InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}}, <>], 
>      InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}}, <>], 
>      InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}}, <>]}

To evaluate these functions at `x` you need to use

```
Through@pfun[50, 1, 1, 1]@x
```

or

```
#[x] & /@ pfun[50, 1, 1, 1]
```

Both return

> {InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}}, <>][x], 
>    InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}}, <>][x], 
>    InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}}, <>][x]}

which can be wrapped with `Evaluate` and used as the first argument of `Plot`. Alternatively, you can use the `Plot` option `Evaluated->True` without the `Evaluate` wrapper.

Answer (score 4):

The combination,

```
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqns, ics}, {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]}, {t, 0, 10},
        {a1, a, b, c}];
Plot[Evaluate[pfun[50, 1, 1, 1]], {t, 0, 10}]
```

also works, giving the same curves.